# A program to cut a big image into a bunch of little images

Tags: images, batch, gimp

I am making a tileset for a game in GIMP, and the thought of cutting out each 
individual piece (the game environment will be destructible, so we're talking about a lot of pieces here) is not a thought I like to consider.

I already have a program to batch rename, and a program to put the pieces back together (in a packed spritesheet), so all I lack is a way to cut them out.

I use Ubuntu as my main OS, but I can get more or less any program working on here, so don't let potential incompatibility prevent you from posting a response.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have ImageMagick installed already, get the [imagemagick](http://apt:imagemagick) package.  It's an incredibly useful piece of software!

See this link for tiling:  http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thankyou very much!